# "ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000" with custom *.o file

Tags: c++, elf, entry-point, readelf

I've compiled a simple object file file and tried to link with `ld`, but it gave that warning. However, the file has `_start` symbol, Here's the `readelf` of the object.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x40
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          59392 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         6
  Section header string table index: 5
(...)
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000040
       000000000000005c  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001040
       0000000000001000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [ 3] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00003400
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018           4     2     8
  [ 4] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003800
       0000000000000400  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 5] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003000
       0000000000000400  0000000000000000           0     0     1
(...)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 2 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000    87 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _start
```

What could be the problem here

Comment: No warning here: `echo 'extern "C" {int _start(){}}' > test.cc && g++ test.cc -c && ld test.o`. Could you include your compile+link command lines and versions your toolchain?

Comment: The thing is that I've compiled the code to the object file with a custom language.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the problem. The `info` of symbol section header must be the index of the `_start` function in the symbol table. But for some reason the linker change that later, but It worked just fine!!